# Comparing two NSDates day, month and year integers

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to compare two NSDates to understand if they are in the same day or not. These are the two dates (the second one is always the current date, NSDate()):

2015-08-23 22:00:00 +0000
2015-08-23 19:13:45 +0000

It seems obvious that the dates are in the same day, as 23 = 23. However I can't seem to be able to establish this in the code. I tried:

1)

```
let date = tripObject["tripDate"] as! NSDate
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let str = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)

let date2 = NSDate()
let dateFormatter2 = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter2.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let str2 = dateFormatter2.stringFromDate(date2)

println(". \(str) and \(str2) .")
```

This gives 2015-08-24 and 2015-08-23

2)

```
let dateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(.CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: tripObject["tripDate"] as! NSDate)
let dateComponents2 = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(.CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: NSDate())
```

This gives different day components.

3)

```
if NSCalendar.currentCalendar().isDate(firstDate!, inSameDayAsDate: secondDate!){
```

4)

```
if NSCalendar.currentCalendar().isDateInToday(the NSDate) {
```

Both 3 and 4 fail.

I am totally lost, any ideas?

Comment: Use NSCalendar.currentCalendar().startOfDayForDate(date) to get dates in beginning of the day and the use compare method

Comment: What do you mean it fails? What are the times in the dates?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`NSCalendar` has a method `isDate:equalToDate:toUnitGranularity:` which does exactly what you need

`date1` and `date2` are the `NSDate` instances to be compared, the result is `Bool`

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
let datesAreInTheSameDay = calendar.isDate(date1, equalToDate: date2, toUnitGranularity: .CalendarUnitDay | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitYear)
```

**Swift 2:**

```
let datesAreInTheSameDay = calendar.isDate(date1, equalToDate: date2, toUnitGranularity: [.Day, .Month, .Year])
```

**Swift 3:**

```
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)!
let datesAreInTheSameDay = calendar.isDate(date1, equalTo: date2, toGranularity:.day)
```

Comment: I tried the first line, it still doesn't work.. Seems that whatever I do the day 23 becomes a 24

Comment: Date1: 2015-08-23 22:00:00 +0000, Date2: 2015-08-23 20:56:30 +0000

Comment: the code is supposed to work, check the time zone of the dates

Comment: It's not supposed to consider the time dates

Comment: I updated the post to set the time zone of the calendar to GMT

Comment: Great thanks, finally works!! I came across the calendar timeZone property but I thought it was read only.

Comment: @vadian this does not work with Swift 3, please update your answer to be compatible with Swift 3

Comment: @JAHelia Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @vadian I'd ask this same question but to compare if a Date is less than or equal another date regardless to time components ? I don't want to open a new question for this, because it's must similar to this one but couldn't find a solution to it unfortunately. would you update your answer ?

Comment: @JAHelia Actually Adnan's answer does that.

Comment: @JAHelia There is another method `calendar.isDate(date1, inSameDayAs: date2)`

Comment: @vadian this won't tell you if date1 is less/greater than or equal date2, I need something like NSComparisonResult for yyyy/MM/dd but still couldn't find any.

Comment: Use Adnan's answer with `OrderedAscending` / `OrderedDescending` which is the equivalent to less / greater than

Answer (score 3):

You can convert both dates to start of the day and then use `compare` method of `NSDate` to compare them

```
   let date1StartOfTheDay = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().startOfDayForDate(date)
   let date2StartOfTheDay = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().startOfDayForDate(date2
   if date1StartOfTheDay.compare(date2StartOfTheDay) == OrderedSame
   {
       //same dates
    }
```

Comment: Tried this, gives . 2015-08-23 22:00:00 +0000 and 2015-08-22 22:00:00 +0000 . where 08-22 is date2 or NSDate(), even if today is the 23rd. If i just print the NSDate() it gives 2015-08-23 19:46:46 +0000

Comment: Can u print date and see what it prints, i think it might be timezone issue

Comment: date = 2015-08-23 22:00:00 +0000

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension:

```
extension NSDate {

    func isEqualToDate2(dateToCompare : NSDate) -> Bool {
        //Declare Variables
        var isEqualTo = false

        //Compare Values
        if self.compare(dateToCompare) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame {
            isEqualTo = true
        }

        //Return Result
        return isEqualTo
    }

}
```

like:

```
if date1.isEqualToDate2(date2) {
...
}
```