# Check Same Dates Inside ForEach Swift

Tags: swift, date, sorting, foreach

How can I check if item 1 date is equal to item 2 date inside the foreach. Can I check the same dates inside the predicate like below without using 2 foreach loops?

```
struct TimedView: View {
static let taskDateFormat: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .long
    return formatter
}()
@State var releaseDate = Date()
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
@FetchRequest var reminder: FetchedResults<CDReminder>
init(){
    var calendar = Calendar.current
    calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
    let dateFrom = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date()) // eg. 2016-10-10 00:00:00
    let dateTo = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: dateFrom)
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format : "date >= %@ AND date == %@", dateFrom as CVarArg)
    self._reminder = FetchRequest(
        entity: CDReminder.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \CDReminder.date, ascending: false)],
        predicate: predicate)
}
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text("Zamanlanmis")
                    .font(.system(size: 40, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.leading)
            List{
                ForEach(reminder, id: \.self) { item in
                    DatedReminderCell(reminder: item, isSelected: false, onComplete: {})
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Now my output is coming like this

[image]

Comment: That depends on what you mean by equal, same date or equal down to the last second or...?

Comment: same date. say that itemOne.date = 01.01.2022 and itemTwo.date = 01.01.2022 so it should return true

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing two NSDates day, month and year integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170565/comparing-two-nsdates-day-month-and-year-integers)

Comment: You are doing *controller work* in the view. Don’t. Compare and filter your stuff somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this complex problem I created a helper file called ScheduledViewHelper. Inside this helper, I have created a new array that has two elements(reminder and date). Inside this helper first I fetched all the reminders from core data then I compared all their date data and when I find a new date I append the date element inside the array. Finally, I sorted those dates and return [ReminderList] to be able to get this array from my ScheduledView.

My ScheduledViewHelper is

```
 public struct ReminderList: Hashable {
    let date: String
    let reminder: [CDReminder]
}

open class ScheduledViewHelper: NSObject {
    public static let shared = ScheduledViewHelper()
    private let viewContext = PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext

    private override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    private func getReminders() -> [CDReminder]  {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<CDReminder> = CDReminder.fetchRequest()
        do {
            let items = try viewContext.fetch(request) as [CDReminder]
            return items
        } catch {
            print("Error occured: ", error)
        }
        return []
    }

    public func getScheduledData() -> [ReminderList] {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        var list: [ReminderList] = []
        var dateList: [String] = []
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        let reminders = getReminders()
        reminders.forEach { (reminder) in
            let date = dateFormatter.string(from: reminder.date!)
            if !dateList.contains(date) && date >= dateFormatter.string(from: Date()) {
                dateList.append(date)
            }
        }
        dateList.forEach { (date) in
            let dateFrom = calendar.startOfDay(for: dateFormatter.date(from: date)!) // eg. 2016-10-10 00:00:00
            let dateTo = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: dateFrom)
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date <= %@ AND date >= %@", dateTo! as NSDate, dateFrom as NSDate)
            let request: NSFetchRequest<CDReminder> = CDReminder.fetchRequest()
            request.predicate = predicate
            do {
                let items = try viewContext.fetch(request) as [CDReminder]
                let newItem = ReminderList(date: date, reminder: items)
                list.append(newItem)
            } catch {
                print("Error occured: ", error)
            }
        }
        return list.sorted {
            $0.date < $1.date
        }
    }

    private func saveContext() {
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            print("Error occured: ", error)
        }
    }

}
```

I added to my ScheduledView those lines:

- created a new var before init() statement

  @State var remindersList : [ReminderList] = []
- just under NavigationView I initialized remindersList with onAppear

  .onAppear {
  remindersList = ScheduledViewHelper.shared.getScheduledData()
  }
- Reorganized my List like this

  List{
  ForEach(remindersList, id: .self) { item in
  VStack(alignment: .leading) {
  Text(item.date)
  ForEach(item.reminder, id: .self) { reminder in
  DatedReminderCell(reminder: reminder, isSelected: false, onComplete: {})
  }
  }
  .foregroundColor(.black)
  }
  }

Answer (score 0):

Date objects are only equal if they represent the exact same instant, down to the fraction of a second.

If you want to see if a date falls on a give month/day/year, you will need to use a Calendar object to generate  beginning_of_day and end_of_day dates and see if each date fall between them.

[**This thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831600/core-data-predicate-date-comparison) includes several examples of that. Most of the code is in Objective-C but it should be pretty easy to translate the approach to Swift, if not the exact code.